# Why some websites recognize data after deleting history/cache/cookies?

Tags: flash, cache, cookies

The following website for example:
myopenid.com

What i do the erase all traces:

1. Firefox -> Clear history -> All (cache,cookies,history,..)
2. Deleting Flash cookies manually (AppData->Roaming->Macromedia->FlashPlayer)
3. changing mac-address -> becomes changing IP address

NO PASSWORDS are saved in Firefox for these Websites.

I am clueless how those few websites can identify me even after doing all that.

Why they still identify me?? Is there something new?

Comment: When you say "recognize data" what kind of data are you talking about?

Comment: username password

Comment: What browser are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a second location

.

> %APPDATA%\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\macromedia.com\support\flashplayer\sys\

[source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Shared_Object#File_locations)

.

Maybe they are [fingerprinting your browser.](http://www.eff.org/press/archives/2010/05/13)

Comment: i knew that, thats common knowledge. Thats why i wrote: AppData->Roaming->Macromedia->FlashPlayer. the reason is definetely not flash-cookie based since i stressed that out by disabling flash. Also i don't think that a company like myopenid would identify me by easy hackable javascript characteristics like screen,resolution etc. its my login we are talking about. thax though for your answer

Comment: Login information is always stored in a cookie or a browser, so something is lingering on your system.."common knowledge" you obviously don't answer many questions here or on forums, I assume nothing, besides you stated you were clueless. ;->